Validating ASP.NET Core EF Identity users in .NET Core Identity
I have written an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API project, which is using a database from an older ASP.NET MVC project (on .NET 4.6).
I have successfully wired up the Identity framework, and I am pulling the IdentityUser out of the database
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MydbContext>();

I know its working correctly because this code:
public AuthenticationController(SignInManager<User> signInManager, UserManager<User> userManager)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(signInManager));
    _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
}

[HttpGet("Authenticate")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
   var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
   var check = _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false);

    if (check.Result.Succeeded)
    {
        return Ok();
    }


    return Ok();
}

The User object is correct, I can see it holds all the correct values.
But when I try and do a CheckPasswordSignInAsync, it always returns FALSE - even though the password is correct, and the legacy ASP.NET MVC project logs in perfectly with it.
I am assuming its something to do with a different password hashing logic, but nowhere in the original project do i see any mention about password hashes, salts or anything of the sorts that I could try copy into the new application. Both apps are working on defaults I presume
I feel like I am sitting with the same issue as
was mentioned here
but their wasn't a real solution, or anything
Note: I also tried adding this, but it didn't help
builder.Services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);


instead of CheckPasswordSignInAsync, i am using
var check = _userManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, user.PasswordHash, Password);

which returns a
PasswordVerificationResult.Success


The _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync() method performs additional checks and does not just verify the provided password.
It checks the following conditions:

If required, does the user have a confirmed email?
If required, does the user have a confirmed phone number?
If required, does the user have a confirmed account?
If supported, is the user locked out?

if any of these checks are not passed the SignInManager will return a failed SignInResult.
If you do not want these checks to be performed or to be ignored, you have a couple of options.
Option 1, Change the default configuration (preferred)
Disable the requirements for signing in. You can do this in your configuration like so:
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;

    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
})

You can read more on configuring ASP.NET Core Identity in the documentation.
Option 2, Validate password in the UserManager
Instead of using the SignInManager, you can use the UserManager to validate the password.
await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password);

This will only validate the password. If it returns true, you can sign the user in without additional checks.
await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true);

Hope this helps!
